# How change the cursor for a mat-radio-button?

Tags: angular-material

I've this mat-radio-button. When the option is disabled, I'd like to make the cursor **no-drop**.

```
<mat-radio-button _ngcontent-c11="" class="mat-radio-button mat-accent b-disabled-radio 
  mat-radio-disabled" value="option['text']" ng-reflect-checked="false" 
  ng-reflect-value="option['text']" ng-reflect-disabled="true" tabindex="-1" 
  id="mat-radio-12">
  <label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-12-input">
    <div class="mat-radio-container">
        <div class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></div>
        <div class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
</mat-radio-button>
```

Using the Chrome DevTools, when I change the value of this rule from default to no-drop, it works, i.e. I can see the cursor change.

```
.mat-radio-disabled, .mat-radio-disabled .mat-radio-label {
     cursor: default; //==> no-drop
 }
```

However, when I copy/paste the rule in the myComponent.Component.css, nothing is happening.

Thanks for helping

Comment: It's probably a specificity issue. Try to use `!important` in your CSS.

Comment: I've added `cursor: no-drop !important;` but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working if you put your styles into global stylesheet: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mu68jp
Put the following code in you global styles (*styles.css*):

```
app-my-component {
  .mat-radio-disabled, .mat-radio-disabled .mat-radio-label {
     cursor: no-drop !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's working. However, what if I want to limit the override to a component?

Comment: then put it in the coomponent selector there. look at my edits